# Intuition: Convexity of Multivariate Functions and Positive Semidefiniteness of the Hessian

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

For a twice differentiable **univariate** function $f(x_1)$, the intuition why $f$ is convex if and only if $f''(x_1) \ge 0$ for all $x_1$ is pretty clear. At least once one has understood the notion of "concave up", i.e., the geometric meaning of the second derivative in terms of the sign/change in slopes as it nicely described e.g., [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/shapeofgraphptii.aspx).

Going now to **multivariate** functions $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$, the "straightforward" lifting of this intuition would be that all the second partial derivatives (i.e., the Hessian matrix) would have to be non-negative for all $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ in order to have f be convex. I would then conclude that once more all slopes would encode a "concave-up" scenario. However, as is well known, the true condition for the convexity of $f$ is that the Hessian matrix need be positive semidefinite (*which in particular implies that some of the partial derivatives may well be negative*).

I am hunting for explanations why this is so / why the straightforward intuition fails, in a very similar way as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599846/hessian-matrix-for-convexity-of-multidimensional-function). The answer there is very nice, however I would very much appreciate one that does not parameterize the function. Especially not in a way, such that the function truly depends only on one variable when setting the parameter to zero. Rather, I would like an explanation that only uses the original function.

To make it more concrete and simpler:

Isn't there a "simple" argumentation for say bivariate quadratic functions $f(x_1, x_2) = x^T Q x + c^Tx$ (with $x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $Q = \begin{bmatrix} q_{11} & q_{12} \\ q_{21} & q_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ symmetric)?

As is nicely explained [here](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Quadratic_function_of_multiple_variables), the Hessian is then just $2Q$. Now, *knowing* that $f$ is convex if and only if $Q$ is positive-semidefinite is fine, but certainly no explanation. The question is now **why is this the right / necessary criterion** and **what is its geometric interpretation**?

How can I relate the $u$ in the condition $u^T Q u \ge 0$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to the convexity of $f$? I hope that if I understand this, then I also know why it would not be sufficient if the Hessian was only non-negative.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, but I think that it perfectly does. The concept is heavily relied on in convex quadratic (in particular semidefinite) optimization (even to "convexify" non-convex problems) and I particularly hope that some experts from this field may be capable to easily answer the question / describe the corresponding intution.

Comment: To clarify, are you just looking for an interesting/nice geometric explanation for intuition as to why we need the full positive definiteness (and showing that positive partials is insufficient)? Or do you want a proof of necessity?

Comment: did you appreciate any of the answers?

Comment: Yes, actually I did very much appreciate both answers but I unfortunately didn't yet find the time to react, especially not in terms of discussing the details. Sorry for that! Now I am a bit irritated that one of the answers which also (had interesting ideas) is gone. I have to work through this more carefully and will then come back.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and convex. A $C^1$ function $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex if and only if the tangent plane to the graph of $f$ at any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ lies below the graph of $f$. This means that at any $x \in \Omega$, for any $y \in \Omega$,
$$f(y) \geq f(x) + Df(x)(y - x).$$
In order to use the Hessian, let's assume $f$ is $C^2$. Since $f$ is $C^2$ on a convex open set we can apply Taylor's theorem:
$$f(y) = f(x) + Df(x)(y - x) + \frac{1}{2}(y - x) \cdot H(x + \theta(y - x))(y - x),$$
where $\theta \in (0, 1)$. Positive semidefiniteness of the hessian $H$ at every point ensures that
$$(y - x) \cdot H(x + \theta(y - x))(y - x) \geq 0,$$
and therefore that $f$ is convex. Conversely, if $H(x)$ is not positive semidefinite at some point $x \in \Omega$, then there exists $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v \cdot H(x)v < 0$. By continuity of $H$, $v \cdot H(y)v < 0$ for $y$ near $x$. Consequently, for $h \in \mathbb{R}$ small,
\begin{align}
f(x + hv) &= f(x) + Df(x)hv + \frac{1}{2}hv \cdot H(x + \theta hv)hv \\
&= f(x) + Df(x)hv + \frac{1}{2}h^2v \cdot H(x + \theta hv)v \\
&< f(x) + Df(x)hv,
\end{align}
which implies that $f$ is not convex.